# MongoDB | Update rows record by record on basis of one field

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-2.x

I want to update the documents/records of a collection in mongodb in python with the `min`/`max`/`avg` of temperature on the basis of a time range.

In the below example suppose time range is given to me "20:09-20:15", then the last row will not be updated rest of the ones will do.

Sample Data:

```
[
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:09", 'temperature': 20}, //1
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:11", 'temperature': 19}, //2 
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:15", 'temperature': 18}, //3
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:18", 'temperature': 18} //4
]
```

Required output:

```
[
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:09", 'temperature': 20, 'MIN': 20, 'MAX': 20, 'AVG': 20}, //1
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:11", 'temperature': 19, 'MIN': 19, 'MAX': 20, 'AVG': 19.5}, //2
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:15", 'temperature': 18, 'MIN': 18, 'MAX': 20, 'AVG': 19}, //3
    {'date': "1-10-2020", 'time': "20:18", 'temperature': 18} //4
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mongo version 4.4+ you can use [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) to achieve this using a pipline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      time: {
        $gte: "20:09",
        $lte: "20:15"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      avg: {
        $avg: "$temperature"
      },
      min: {
        $min: "$temperature"
      },
      max: {
        $max: "$temperature"
      },
      root: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$root"
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$root",
          {
            "MIN": "$min",
            "MAX": "$max",
            "AVG": "$avg"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $merge: {
      into: "collection",
      on: "_id",
      whenMatched: "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/R7_9Lj2xsLa)

If you're on a lesser Mongo version you have to split this into 2 calls, First use the same `$group` stage to fetch results, then use the values to update: (i'll write this one in python as you've tagged you're using `pymongo`)

```
results = list(collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "time": {
                "$gte": "20:09",
                "$lte": "20:15"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": None,
            "avg": {
                "$avg": "$temperature"
            },
            "min": {
                "$min": "$temperature"
            },
            "max": {
                "$max": "$temperature"
            },
            "root": {
                "$push": "$$ROOT"
            }
        }
    }
]))

collection.update_many(
    {
        "time": {
            "$gte": "20:09",
            "$lt": "20:15"
        }
    },
    {
        "$set": {
            "MAX": results[0]["max"],
            "MIN": results[0]["min"],
            "AVG": results[0]["avg"],
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Hi thank for the reply, but it will update all the rows with max/min/value right (baiscally combing result of all 4 rows)?

I want to update the rows one by one like the first record would be temperature value of itself, then the second one will be the result of first and second row and so on..